# Iterating a dictionary to create a DataFrame with the column names being the dictionary keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a `Pandas` `DataFrame` with each column being an individual stock's percentage change, indexed by date. I am having trouble with taking the percentage change, adding it to an empty `DataFrame` and naming that column the stock symbol.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

stocks = {'xom': '2014-01-01', 'dvn': '2013-01-01', 'aapl': '2013-01-01'}
for key in stocks:
    L = []
    price = web.get_data_yahoo(key, stocks[key])['Adj Close']
    change = price.diff().cumsum()
    perChange = change / price.iloc[0]
```

everything goes as planned up to this point...

```
    L.append(perChange)
    df = pd.DataFrame(L)
    df.columns = keys
```

Comment: where is `keys` defined? What is the issue? Can you please update the complete traceback?

Comment: Not your question, but you don't need to calculate change. Just do `price/price.iloc[0]-1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `L` outside the loop, so it does not get re-instantiated with each iteration. If you make `L` a dict, then the keys of the dict will become columns of the DataFrame formed by  `df = pd.DataFrame(L)`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web

stocks = {'xom': '2014-01-01', 'dvn': '2013-01-01', 'aapl': '2013-01-01'}
L = dict()
for stock, date in stocks.items():
    price = web.get_data_yahoo(stock, date)['Adj Close']
    change = price.diff().cumsum()
    perChange = change / price.iloc[0]
    L[stock] = perChange
df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print(df.head())
```

yields

```
                aapl       dvn  xom
Date                               
2013-01-02       NaN       NaN  NaN
2013-01-03 -0.012622  0.017728  NaN
2013-01-04 -0.040125  0.040412  NaN
2013-01-07 -0.045772  0.040793  NaN
2013-01-08 -0.043203  0.033359  NaN
```